# Scheduled task was not triggered after DST

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled, spring-context

I am using a scheduled task with annotation:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 0 * * ?", zone = "Europe/Bratislava")
```

This task was successfully triggered every day, but after the Daylight saving time (DST) change, the task did not start on 2022/03/28 at 0.30 AM. The day after (2022/03/29), task was triggered again and continue triggering every day according to cron expression.

Other scheduled task used in application ran properly with annotation below:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * *", zone = "Europe/Bratislava")
```

Annotation is used from dependency:

> org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.10

I am struggling to find out why scheduled task did not run. Does anyone know the answer, please?